# TSOT-23-6 vs SOT-23-6

Tags: surface-mount

What is the difference between a TSOT-23-6 and a SOT-23-6?

I know one is thinner. But in what dimension? I have looked in my PCB editor and they both have the same footprint.

Any clarity appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've successfully used a SOT footprint for TSOT parts.

As far as I can tell, what differences there are are only in part height, which is not important from the board layout perspective.

Comment: Not important until you are having to put your device in a case or stacking pcbs or other components, such as LCDs :-)

Comment: Yes, I believe the T in these stands for "Thin".

Comment: @Kellenjb - As I said, it's not important from a board layout perspective. Packaging and mechanical design is a different can of worms.

Answer (score 14):

The difference between a TSOT-23-6 and a SOT-23-6 is the height, apparent from the two PDF files below. The exact dimensions varies between manufacturers.

From [Packaging Information - Plastic Packages](http://www.intersil.com/en/support/packaginginfo.html#PLASTIC/):

1. SOT-23-6. [6 Lead Small Outline Transistor Plastic Package (SOT)](http://www.intersil.com/data/pk/P6.064.pdf) (PDF, 103 KB). 2.8 x 1.6 x **1.15** mm (body)
2. TSOT-23-6. [6 Lead **Thin** Small Outline Transistor Plastic Package (TSOT)](http://www.intersil.com/data/pk/P6.064B.pdf) (PDF, 52 KB). 2.8 x 1.6 x **0.87** mm (body)

Answer (score 5):

Check the datasheet for the part you are using. There is usually a dimensioned drawing in the back, although some manufactures put them in a separate documents buried somewhere on their website. There can be small differences in package dimensions (of the same designation) from different manufactures. So if it is import in your design, it is best to refer to the specific documentation for that part.